# as3 datagrid column sort with special function

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, datagrid

Im using datagrid component in an AS3 air project. I get datas from sql by php and include into datagrid. My problem is I want to change the sorting methods. For example, when you work with Arrays you can sort the arrays with special functions.. **For example; arrayName.sort(functionName)**

How can I use this func in a specific datagrid columns :

```
function orderLastName(a, b):int 
{ 
    var lastName:RegExp = /\b\S+$/; 
    var name1 = a.match(lastName); 
    var name2 = b.match(lastName); 

    if (name1 < name2) 
    { 
        return -1; 
    } 
    else if (name1 > name2) 
    { 
        return 1; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return 0; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you've said the answer in your question. Just do this:

```
var dataArray:Array = dataGrid.dataProvider.toArray();

dataArray.sort(myfunc);

dataGrid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(dataArray);
```

Also if you just wanna do that to a specific column, copy the data of that column to a new array from the dataArray and perform your sort, set the data back in the dataArray and reset the data provider. Note you also may need to invalidate the stage in order to force the list to redraw. Just do:

```
stage.invalidate();
```

Comment: It took me while to search a working example. And I couldnt find any useful example. This one is what I'm looking for. Thanks Ascension